# Restore missing Downloads folder due to missing link

Tags: windows-vista, windows-explorer

I originally had the Downloads folder in my user profile redirected to a folder on a hard drive which went bad. So I removed the hard drive, but now the Downloads folder is gone altogether.  How do I restore this folder and point it back to my original C: drive?

Note: Googling for this revealed nothing useful. I found some links that suggested typing "shell:downloads" in the Start prompt, but that doesn't do anything for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See this article : [How to Restore a Missing Personal User Folder in Vista](http://www.vistax64.com/tutorials/148461-personal-user-folder-restore-missing-folder.html).

Go through all the steps described in the above article, although I expect that the one you're looking for is Option three sub-option 4. This requires that the Download directory exist in its customary place : `C:\Users\$user-name$\Downloads` .

Answer (score -2):

If you intentionally/mistakenly deleted the Download folder it will re-create in:

My Documents > Downloads

You can also check it by downloading something and see where it is stored.