# My Downloads folder disappeared

Tags: windows-7

In Windows 7, my *Downloads* folder in my user directory disappeared. How can I recreate it? I just created as a new folder, but it does not have the special folder icon that it used to have. That means it is not a system folder.

How can I recover my original Downloads folder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try with this answer, it's for Vista but might work for Windows 7. Check in the website, at the bottom, recover the Downloads registry key.

[Restore missing Downloads folder due to missing link](https://superuser.com/questions/67410/restore-missing-downloads-folder-due-to-missing-link)

Answer (score 0):

The special icon is just a special icon.

I would try downloading something using Internet Explorer and see if that recreates the folder, otherwise, just create it yourself. There isn't anything really special about the Downloads folder.